# como faço pra tirar as barras de rolagem do meu iframe por meio do css?

Tags: html, css

to fazendo um exercicio pra ocultar as barras de rolagens do iframe mas algo deu errado! de novo !!!

```js
function mudaFoto (foto)
 {
  document.getElementById("icone").src=foto;
 }
```

```css
@charset"UTF-8";
section#conteudo {
 width: 1000px;
 margin: auto;
 
}
iframe#frame-spec {
 width: 380px;
 height: 280px;
 border: none;
 overflow: hidden;
}
iframe#frame-spec::-webkit-scrollbar {
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang=pt-br>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <title>Tudo sobre Google Glas</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/estilo.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/specs.css"/>
  
 </head>
 <script language="javascript" src="_javascript/funcoes.js"></script>
 <body>
 <div id="interface">
 <header id="cabecalho">
   <hgroup>
   <h1>Google Glass</h1>
   <h2> A revolução do Google está chegando</h2>
    </hgroup>
   <img id="icone"src="_imagens/glass-oculos-preto-peq.png">
  <nav id="menu">

   <h1>Menu Principal</h1>

   <ul type="disc">

   <li onmouseover="mudaFoto('_imagens/home.png')" onmouseout="mudaFoto('_imagens/especificacoes.png')"><a href="index.html">Home<a/></li>
   <li onmouseover="mudaFoto('_imagens/especificacoes.png')" onmouseout="mudaFoto('_imagens/especificacoes.png')"><a href="specs.html">Especificações<a/></li>
   <li onmouseover="mudaFoto('_imagens/fotos.png')" onmouseout="mudaFoto('_imagens/especificacoes.png')"><a href="fotos.html">Fotos<a/></li>
   <li onmouseover="mudaFoto('_imagens/multimidia.png')" onmouseout="mudaFoto('_imagens/especificacoes.png')"><a href="multimidia.html">Multimídia<a/></li>
   <li onmouseover="mudaFoto('_imagens/contato.png')" onmouseout="mudaFoto('_imagens/especificacoes.png')"><a href="Fale-conosco.html">Fale conosco<a/></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
<section id="corpo-full">
 <article id="noticia-principal">
  <header id="cabecalho-artigo">
   <hgroup>
   <h3>Glass > Especificações</h3>
   <h1>Raio-X no Google Glass</h1>
   <h2>por Gustavo Guanabara</h2>
   <h3 class="direita">Atualizado em 01/Maio/2013 </h3>
   </hgroup>
  </header>
  <p>Clique em qualquer área destacada da imagem para ter mais informações sobre os recursos do Google Glass. Qualquer ponto vermelho vai te levar a um lugar cheio de novas informações.</p>
  <section id="conteudo">
   <img src="_imagens/glass-esquema-marcado.jpg"/>
   <iframe src="google-glass.html" name="janela" id="frame-spec"></iframe>
  </section>
</article>
</section>

  <footer id="rodape">

  <p>Copyright &copy; 2013 - by Gustavo Guanabara<br/>
  <a href="http://facebook.com/cursoemvideo"target="blank">Facebook</a> | 
  <a href="http://twitter.com/cursoemvideo"target="blank">Twitter</a></p>
  </footer>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: `<iframe src="google-glass.html" name="janela" id="frame-spec"></iframe>`

Vá até o arquivo que você esta colocando no iframe no caso do seu creio que seja google-glass.html e no head dele coloque

`<style>

body{
  overflow: hidden !important;
  }
  
</style>`

Comment: a maioria dos navegadores ainda suporta  scrolling  `<iframe src=""  scrolling="no" scroll="no" ></iframe>` Google Chrome Versão 60.0.3112.113 (Official Build) (64 bits) `scrolling="no"`  não funciona, porém  `scroll="no"` funciona

Comment: estou fazendo este mesmo curso e esta solução não resolveu meu problema (que por sua vez é o mesmo citado acima), então acrescentei **scrolling="no"** no **iframe** que resolveu para todos os navegadores (atuais) que testei. ficou assim: `<iframe id="frame-spec" src="google-glass.html" name="janela" scrolling="no"></iframe>` Inclusive tirei as linhas desnecessárias do meu CSS3

Comment: Pessoal que também está com o problema da barra que não some, encontrei a seguinte solução para o problema: no style do arquivo `google-glass.html` coloque: `body::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; }` espero ter ajudado, pois tive o mesmo problema.